# is there a Relationship between duplicity of EigenValue and dimension of it's EigenSpace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

giving characteristic polynomial of a matrix (Which has eigenvalues with it's duplicity) how can we understand the dimension of eigenspace of each eigenvalue without direct calculation?

in addition, is there a relationship between the power of eigenvalue in minimal polynomial and dim of corresponding eigenSpace?

=========

at least, Can we discuss about Zero EigenValues and Null Space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power of the eigenvalue in the characteristic polynomial is called *algebraic multiplicity* and the dimension of its eigenspace *geometric multiplicity*. One can show that

$$1 \leq \text{ geometric mult.} \leq \text{algebraic mult.}$$
always holds. Note that equality does **not** hold in general, e.g. take

$$\pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}$$

which has char. poly. $\chi(\lambda) = \lambda^2$ but the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda = 0$ is $span \pmatrix{0\\1}$.

For any $n \times n$-matrix $A$ of rank $r < n$, $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue and we have

$$\text{geometric mult.} = \dim \ker A = n-r.$$

However, the algebraic mult. may still be strictly greater than the geometr. mult. (see example above).

Comment: Thanks; i Just found a helpful theorem: "A linear operator is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial splits into distinct linear factors."